# How do I select the top 10 values based on specific criteria?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas

I would like to select the top ten products based on revenue, for three different weeks:

[image]

The weeks change automatically (for example, this week I have 5/27, but next week it will automatically update to 6/3).

My dataset automatically updates every week and looks as follows:

[image]

I've tried using INDEX MATCH and LARGE, but I couldn't figure out how to do it automatically.

I expect the output to be a formula that would automatically update every time my dataset updates by adding additional weeks' revenue.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Do you keep adding more and more columns to the right of the 5/27/2019 column?

Comment: Yes, it automatically adds more columns to the right.

Comment: OK - and the products go on for a lot more rows?

Comment: Exactly. There are a total of 45 products.

Comment: Here's a copy of my sheet, thank you for taking a look @player0: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ZBZ-bGTIpRu_y22_W13Le2UzZDmKHJu5mW6RlRkIJXg/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: I just added an example for this week. I hope this is helpful, but please do let me know if it isn't clear yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, well I generated some random data before the sheet was shared and it turned out that the best week was last week:

[image]

Original data in sheet Data:

[image]

**Formulas:**

B1

```
=index(Data!B1:1,COUNTA(Data!1:1)-1)
```

D1

```
=index(Data!B1:1,COUNTA(Data!1:1)-2)
```

F1

```
=ArrayFormula(index(Data!B1:1,match(max(mmult(transpose(row(Data!B2:index(Data!B2:B,counta(A:A)-1)))^0,Data!B2:index(Data!B2:Z,counta(A:A)-1,counta(Data!1:1)-1))),
mmult(transpose(row(Data!B2:index(Data!A2:B,counta(A:A)-1)))^0,Data!B2:index(Data!B2:Z,counta(A:A)-1,counta(Data!1:1)-1)),0)))
```

A3

```
=sortn({Data!A2:A,index(Data!B2:Z,0,counta(Data!1:1)-1)},10,0,2,false)
```

C3

```
=sortn({Data!A2:A,index(Data!B2:Z,0,counta(Data!1:1)-2)},10,0,2,false)
```

E3

```
=sortn({Data!A2:A,index(Data!B2:Z,0,match(F1,Data!B1:1,0))},10,0,2,false)
```

Comment: Thank you so much, Tom. If you have the formula in handy, I would love to see it!

Comment: No problem. I had fun answering a slightly different question than the one that's become clear from the spreadsheet.

Answer (score 1):

### B4:

```
={ARRAYFORMULA(INDIRECT("Dataset!"&ADDRESS(1, MATCH(WEEKNUM(TODAY(), 21),
 WEEKNUM(INDIRECT("Dataset!A1:"&ADDRESS(1, COUNTA(Dataset!A1:1), 4)), 21), 0), 4))),
 ARRAYFORMULA(SUM(INDIRECT("Dataset!"&ADDRESS(2, MATCH(INDIRECT("Dataset!"&
 ADDRESS(1, MATCH(WEEKNUM(TODAY(), 21), WEEKNUM(INDIRECT("Dataset!A1:"&
 ADDRESS(1, COUNTA(Dataset!A1:1), 4)), 21), 0), 4)),
 Dataset!1:1, 0),4)&":"&ADDRESS(ROWS(Dataset!A:A), MATCH(INDIRECT("Dataset!"&
 ADDRESS(1, MATCH(WEEKNUM(TODAY(), 21), WEEKNUM(INDIRECT("Dataset!A1:"&
 ADDRESS(1, COUNTA(Dataset!A1:1), 4)), 21), 0), 4)), Dataset!1:1, 0),4))))}
```

### B5:

```
={ARRAYFORMULA(INDEX(Dataset!B1:1, MATCH(MAX(MMULT(TRANSPOSE(ROW(
 Dataset!B2:INDEX(Dataset!B2:B, COUNTA(Dataset!A:A)-1)))^0, 
 Dataset!B2:INDEX(Dataset!B2:Z, COUNTA(Dataset!A:A)-1, 
 COUNTA(Dataset!1:1)-1))), MMULT(TRANSPOSE(ROW(
 Dataset!B2:INDEX(Dataset!A2:B, COUNTA(Dataset!A:A)-1)))^0,
 Dataset!B2:INDEX(Dataset!B2:Z, COUNTA(Dataset!A:A)-1, COUNTA(Dataset!1:1)-1)), 0))),
 ARRAYFORMULA(SUM(INDIRECT("Dataset!"&ADDRESS(2, MATCH(INDEX(Dataset!B1:1, 
 MATCH(MAX(MMULT(TRANSPOSE(ROW(
 Dataset!B2:INDEX(Dataset!B2:B, COUNTA(Dataset!A:A)-1)))^0, 
 Dataset!B2:INDEX(Dataset!B2:Z, COUNTA(Dataset!A:A)-1, 
 COUNTA(Dataset!1:1)-1))), MMULT(TRANSPOSE(ROW(
 Dataset!B2:INDEX(Dataset!A2:B, COUNTA(Dataset!A:A)-1)))^0,
 Dataset!B2:INDEX(Dataset!B2:Z, COUNTA(Dataset!A:A)-1, COUNTA(Dataset!1:1)-1)), 0)), 
 Dataset!1:1, 0), 4)&":"&ADDRESS(ROWS(Dataset!A:A), MATCH(INDEX(Dataset!B1:1, 
 MATCH(MAX(MMULT(TRANSPOSE(ROW(
 Dataset!B2:INDEX(Dataset!B2:B, COUNTA(Dataset!A:A)-1)))^0, 
 Dataset!B2:INDEX(Dataset!B2:Z, COUNTA(Dataset!A:A)-1, 
 COUNTA(Dataset!1:1)-1))), MMULT(TRANSPOSE(ROW(
 Dataset!B2:INDEX(Dataset!A2:B, COUNTA(Dataset!A:A)-1)))^0,
 Dataset!B2:INDEX(Dataset!B2:Z, COUNTA(Dataset!A:A)-1, 
 COUNTA(Dataset!1:1)-1)), 0)), Dataset!1:1, 0), 4))))}
```

### B6:

```
={ARRAYFORMULA(INDIRECT("Dataset!"&ADDRESS(1, MATCH(WEEKNUM(TODAY(), 21),
 WEEKNUM(INDIRECT("Dataset!A1:"&ADDRESS(1, COUNTA(Dataset!A1:1), 4)), 21), 0), 4)))-7,
 ARRAYFORMULA(SUM(INDIRECT("Dataset!"&ADDRESS(2, MATCH(INDIRECT("Dataset!"&
 ADDRESS(1, MATCH(WEEKNUM(TODAY(), 21), WEEKNUM(INDIRECT("Dataset!A1:"&
 ADDRESS(1, COUNTA(Dataset!A1:1), 4)), 21), 0), 4))-7,
 Dataset!1:1, 0),4)&":"&ADDRESS(ROWS(Dataset!A:A), MATCH(INDIRECT("Dataset!"&
 ADDRESS(1, MATCH(WEEKNUM(TODAY(), 21), WEEKNUM(INDIRECT("Dataset!A1:"&
 ADDRESS(1, COUNTA(Dataset!A1:1), 4)), 21), 0), 4))-7, Dataset!1:1, 0), 4))))}
```

### E5:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA({
 QUERY({Dataset!$A$2:$A, INDIRECT("Dataset!"&
 ADDRESS(2,                      MATCH(F$3, Dataset!$A$1:$1, 0), 4)&":"&
 ADDRESS(ROWS(Dataset!$A2:$A)+1, MATCH(F$3, Dataset!$A$1:$1, 0), 4))}, 
 "order by Col2 desc limit 10", 0),
 QUERY({Dataset!$A$2:$A, INDIRECT("Dataset!"&
 ADDRESS(2,                      MATCH(H$3, Dataset!$A$1:$1, 0), 4)&":"&
 ADDRESS(ROWS(Dataset!$A2:$A)+1, MATCH(H$3, Dataset!$A$1:$1, 0), 4))}, 
 "order by Col2 desc limit 10", 0),
 QUERY({Dataset!$A$2:$A, INDIRECT("Dataset!"&
 ADDRESS(2,                      MATCH(J$3, Dataset!$A$1:$1, 0), 4)&":"&
 ADDRESS(ROWS(Dataset!$A2:$A)+1, MATCH(J$3, Dataset!$A$1:$1, 0), 4))},
 "order by Col2 desc limit 10", 0)})
```

[image: 0]

Comment: @ASE answer and your sheet updated. formulas in B4, B5 and B6 are auto-changing based on if today's date falls in weeknum and cross-references it to data